# Is it possible to have an additional column of % similarity in the BLAST 2.2.26 output file?

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I am using the standalone BLAST program for which i have a query sequence along with a locally created database. As the output file, has something called %identity which identifies exact character matches, is there a way to add a column of % similarity too?  Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using BLAST+ and that by % similarity you mean % positive-scoring matches. There is a format specifier called `ppos` that will return the % positive-scoring matches. This value matches the `Positives` value you see on a BLAST done on the web.

Here is an example command line:

```
blastp -query protein.fa -db proteindb -outfmt '6 std ppos'
```

The 1st 12 fields will be the `std` output of query name, subject name, etc.. and the 13th field will be the % positive-scoring matches.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. Could you please tell me the significance of these positive scoring matches. I mean, does it consider the substitution of similar type amino acids. I searched about it but couldnt find much.

Comment: Positive matches are any two amino acids that have a positive score in the substitution matrix used for the BLAST search. The default is BLOSUM62 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOSUM).